# GWT Rest callback in Activity always empty/null

Tags: java, google-app-engine, rest, gwt, mvp

At first I want to say that I'm not sure if it's the correct way to implement my callback into the Activity class. My goal is to fetch a list of users from a db and set them into my view.

```
public class UserListActivity extends AbstractActivity implements UserListView.Presenter<GWTUser> {

    private List<GWTUser> users;

    @Override
    public void start(AcceptsOneWidget panel, EventBus eventBus) {
        view.setPresenter(this);
        fetchUsers();
        if (getUsers() == null) {
            setUsers(new ArrayList<GWTUser>());
        }

        view.setUserList(getUsers());
        panel.setWidget(view.asWidget());

    }

    @Override
    public void fetchUsers() {

        Defaults.setServiceRoot(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL());
        UserAdminRestService userService = GWT.create(UserAdminRestService.class);
        ((RestServiceProxy)userService).setResource(new Resource("/user"));

        userService.getUsers(new MethodCallback<List<GWTUser>>() {



            @Override
            public void onFailure(Method method, Throwable exception) {
                // TODO getUsers error handling
                System.out.println(exception.getMessage().toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Method method, List<GWTUser> response) {
                setUsers(response);
            }

        });

    }


    private void setUsers(List<GWTUser> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    private List<GWTUser> getUsers() {
        return this.users;
    }
```

The Rest call basically works because I can  see the response in my Development Mode (Eclipse) but when I try to debug this procedure the `MethodCallback` got overstepped and my users list is always empty. I'm not sure where the problem is, seems like it has something to do with when to call the `fetchUsers` method. Or it run-time or compile-time depending, not sure. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed the problem by setting the the arraylist into the view afterthe response meaning

```
@Override
public void start(AcceptsOneWidget panel, EventBus eventBus) {
    view.setPresenter(this);
    fetchUsers();
    panel.setWidget(view.asWidget());

}

@Override
        public void onSuccess(Method method, List<GWTUser> response) {
            view.setUserList(response);
        }
```

So the actual user list is only set after the response.

Answer (score 1):

The following code

```
if (getUsers() == null) {
        setUsers(new ArrayList<GWTUser>());
    }
```

is executed immediately - before your service had a chance to receive a response. You need to move this code inside the onSuccess method in your callback:

```
if (response == null) {
        setUsers(new ArrayList<GWTUser>());
    } else {
        setUsets(response);
    }
```

Comment: no. the app is simply not waiting for the response therefore the array is always null. It steps over the MethodCall ( eclipse: `Sending http request: GET /user/users ,timeout:0`) so the array stays null. and init the view. but the response follows afterwards.

Comment: This is exactly what I said.